# Finding the model of sound card?

Tags: windows-xp, sound-card

I have a pc and I want to find the model of its sound card to download its drivers, I lost the CD came with the system. I use windows XP. Is there a way to find this info inside the system?

Comment: its a long shot, but have you tried Windows Update? it may be able to detect and download the necessary drivers for you

Answer (score 1):

Go into Device Manager and get the vendor and product IDs. From there it should just be a quick Google search to discover the brand and model.

Comment: I've already checked there buddy but the manufacturer part is unknown if you mean there by vendor ID

Comment: Examine the properties of the device in order to find the IDs.

Comment: Windows doesn't always show these in an opaque way. For example, it might be in Hardware Ids, then you'll have to look at the VEN_XXXX part and DEV_XXXX part.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to get the device information is to type

dxdiag

into a run command, select no when prompted to check drivers then go to the sound tab

Winkey+R gets a run box.

Or try one of these utilities

http://www.halfdone.com/ukd/

http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html

Comment: here I get this message:"No sound card was found.  If one is expected, you should install a sound driver provided by the hardware manufacturer."what should I do know?

Comment: follow Ignacio's advice using properties in device manager

Comment: Check my edit to my answer.